# Array implementation of stack

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I wrote this program and it supposed to test for the correct use of the three grouping symbols "(",")";"[","]"; and "{","}". It is using the array implementation of the stacks and supposed to evaluate if it is good string or a bad string. For example: (a+b), [(a-b)+c] would be good and )a+b( etc. would be bad string. When i run the program i get only one error. I thought i am missing a semi-colon or something, but after looking through the code several time,i can't find it. Maybe i got tunnel vision. Can you please see what the problem here is? This is the error: project1.cpp:41: error: expected initializer before 'while'.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

const int DefaultListSize = 100;
typedef char Elem;

class Astack {
private:
    int size;
    int top;
    Elem *listArray;
public:
    Astack (int sz = DefaultListSize)
    {size = sz; top= 0; listArray = new Elem[sz];}
    ~Astack() {delete [] listArray;}
    void clear() {top=0;}
    bool push(const Elem& item) {
            if (top == size) return false;
    else {listArray[top++] = item; return true;}}
    bool pop(Elem& it) {
    if (top==0) return false;
    else {it = listArray[--top]; return true;}}
    bool topValue(Elem& it) const {
    if (top==0) return false;
    else {it = listArray[top-1]; return true;}}
    bool isEmpty() const {if (top==0) return true;
     else return false;}
     int length() const{return top;}
}; //end of class Astack

Astack s;

const string LEFTGROUP="([{";
const string RIGHTGROUP=")]}";

int main()

while (!EOF) {
  while (!EOL) {
   ch = getc();
   if (ch == LEFTGROUP[0]) {
      s.push(ch);
      }
   if (ch == LEFTGROUP[1] {
      s.push(ch);
      }
   if (ch == LEFTGROUP[2] {
      s.push(ch);
      }
    } //checking for openers

   while (!EOL) {
    ch = getc();
    if (s.top() == LEFTGROUP[0]) {
       if (ch == RIGHTGROUP[0]) {
          s.pop();
          }
         }
    if (s.top() == LEFTGROUP[1]) {
       if (ch == RIGHTGROUP[1]) {
          s.pop();
          }
         }
    if (s.top() == LEFTGROUP[2]) {
       if (ch == RIGHTGROUP[2]) {
          s.pop();
          }
         }
    if (!s.empty()) {
      cout<<"Bad String."<<endl;
    else {
      cout<<"Good String."endl;
     }
    }
   }

 return 0;
```

Comment: What have *included* the headers *inside* the class?

Comment: wait a minute. ***there is no while in this code.***

Comment: oops lemme edit the code

Comment: @UmNyobe I'd guess `while` might be used by some of these obscure macros.

Comment: There we go. That's the code

Comment: this is really ironic. A program which purpose is to check for semicolons correctness cannot compile because there is a semicolon missing...

Comment: `expected initializer` error means you are putting an variable/function/class name out of no where. It happens usually when the initilizers like `int/double/structure/class` are mistyped or misused.

Comment: It's quite ironic that you were bitten by a mismatched `}` in writing code for this assignment. May I suggest an editor that highlights matching braces, parentheses and other symbols that come in pairs?

Comment: Goodness, may I suggest an indentation style that makes finsing missing braces easier?  :P

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a { at the beginning of `int main()`. You should also end with }

```
int main(){
    //your while code
    return 0;
}
```